# String manipulation with C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I need help with string manipulation in c#.

I have string with words and empty spaces between them(I have more than one empty spaces between words, empty spaces are dynamic).
I need to replace empty spaces with dash "-"

I have something like this:

```
string stringForManipulation  = "word1    word2  word3";
```

I need to have this:

```
"word1-word2-word3"
```

Tnx

Comment: This question says "give me the codez". Show that you have tried something first before demanding a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(stringForManipulation , @"\s+", "-");
```

`s` means whitespace and `+` means one or more occurence.

Answer (score 6):

You can use regular expressions:

```
string stringForManipulation = "word1    word2  word3";
string result = Regex.Replace(stringForManipulation, @"\s+", "-");
```

This will replace all occurences of one or more whitespace to "-".

Answer (score 3):

For thoose without knowledge of regular expressions, it can be achieved by simple split-join operation:

```
string wordsWithDashes = stringForManipulation.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Join('-')
```

Comment: It can ... but this is one of those rare cases where regexes are the better answer as the regex solution is simpler and easier to read.

Comment: I agree that Regex code is shorter, but there're many people who are completely new to programming and don't know about regular expressions.

Comment: @cyberj0g - ...in which case they should definitely learn that regex is a thing. I'm not convinced that your solution is easier to comprehend for someone new to programming. Also, stating that "it can be done without regex" is good and true, but please add the "why it should be done without regex" part.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
string result=Regex.Replace(str , @"\s+", "-")
```

Will replace single or multiple spaces with single '-'

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
string stringForManipulation  = "word1    word2  word3"; 
string wordsWithDashes  = String.Join(" ", stringForManipulation.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Replace(" ", "-");
```

Created a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YTCKd)